# Using CRAN packages inside SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark

If I wanted to use a standard R package like MXNet inside SparkR, is this possible ? Can standard CRAN packages be used inside the Spark distributed environment without considering a local vs a Spark Dataframe. Is the strategy in working with large data sets in R and Spark to use a Spark dataframe, whittle down the Dataframe and then convert it to a local data.frame to use the standard CRAN package ? Is there another strategy that I'm not aware of ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can standard CRAN packages be used inside the Spark distributed environment without considering a local vs a Spark Dataframe.

No, they cannot.

> Is the strategy in working with large data sets in R and Spark to use a Spark dataframe, whittle down the Dataframe and then convert it to a local `data.frame`.

Sadly, most of the time this is what you do.

> Is there another strategy that I'm not aware of ?

`dapply` and `gapply` functions in Spark 2.0 can apply arbitrary R code to the partitions or groups.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'll look into the dapply and gapply functions.